# mobile paypal return without $_POST variables

Tags: php, mobile, paypal

On my application I am using the post variables from a completed transactions (e.g. transaction reference and amount) on return from the checkout and payment completion on Paypal.

The ones I am using are:

```
$_POST['custom']
$_POST['txn_id']
$_POST['mc_gross']
```

This works fine on the normal site, however when testing on my mobile no $_POST variables are returned to the complete page.

I do have an IPN set up so could do verification from that way - it just seems very odd that via the normal site this works fine and via the mobile site is doesn't appear to have the same functionality?

Comment: can you change the request into `$_REQUEST` see if it's displaying

Comment: This is just showing the $_GET variables I have set in my return url. Should I try the return url without additional parameters?

Comment: Yes please, I think paypal return `$_GET` on mobile.

Comment: Ah, I've just cleared all of the extra parameters from my url and nothing is showing for $_REQUEST or $_GET.

I've tried removing the [rm] parameter (previously it was 2), and changing it to 1 to try and force the get but still no luck.

Comment: I assume your using Developer callback, you can check there if what kind of return value there sending also you're using REST API V2?

Comment: Just good old fashioned cart upload via a form I'm afraid.

Comment: I think it's already depreciated, I'm using that before and it cause me lot of problem so I switch using REST in the paypal developer which is updated and complete parameters, I suggest you do switch to check how's your transaction process.

Comment: No problem, the more you get used to the REST api, the more the integration you could work into. Lot's of framework and ebusiness are using REST.